# How can I replace one pair of character with multiple occurrence in a string?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsregularexpression

**Original String is:** This is a sentence with (noun) (verb) (adverb).

Original sentence has three occurrence of (). I need the last one intact but replace rest with @""

**Required String**: This is a sentence with (adverb).

I can do it with NSRange but I am looking for NSRegularExpression pattern.
Also which is more efficient, one with NSRange or the NSRegularExpression.

**CODE**

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\(.*?\\)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
NSString *newString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:modify options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [modify length]) withTemplate:@""];
```

**Output:**: This is a sentence with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the match ranges themselves and do the replacement manually, ignoring the last one.

```
NSMutableString* newString = [modify mutableCopy];
NSArray<NSTextCheckingResult*>* matches = [regex matchesInString:newString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, newString.length)];
if (matches.count >= 2)
{
    // Enumerate backwards so that each replacement doesn't invalidate the other ranges
    for (NSInteger i = matches.count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        NSTextCheckingResult* result = matches[i];
        [newString replaceCharactersInRange:result.range withString:@""];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is straightforward. I did not know about this protocol. This solved my problem.